# How to delete data pertaining to a specific game for a specific user on Nintendo Switch

Tags: nintendo-switch

In summary, I have six users set up on our Nintendo Switch and a number of games installed and saved data for each game and user.

I know I can go into **System Settings > Data Management** to manage/delete data, but we're a bit nervous about how this works and the info on Nintendo's site is a little ambiguous.

How do I delete game data for a specific game for a specific user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complete these steps:

1. From the HOME Menu, select System Settings.
2. Scroll down and select Data Management, then Delete Save Data. (If prompted, enter your Parental Controls PIN.)
3. Select the game title for which you want to delete the save data.
4. If available, **select the User for which you want to delete the save data**, or select Delete All Save Data for this Software. To confirm, select Delete Save Data.

Source, [Nintendo support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27449/%7E/how-to-manage-%2F-delete-game-save-data).